# Geolocation Callbacks never execute even the error call back

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, geolocation

The code stops at this part nothing else happens it passes the condition then stops it doesn't fire any callbacks am stuck here & my app just fails to deliver.

```
src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js";
src = "//maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2.x&amp;key=AIzaSyD4iE2xVSpkLLOXoyqT-RuPwURN3ddScAI";

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
    }
}

function success(position) {
    //Trials.GetLocationService.setLocation("F"); just testing something i commented it out so it's not the proplem
    printAddress(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
}

function printAddress(latitude, longitude) {
    // set up the Geocoder object
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    // turn coordinates into an object
    var yourLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // find out info about our location
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': yourLocation }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                $('body').append('<p>Your Address:<br />' +
                    results[0].formatted_address + '</p>');
            } else {
                error('Google did not return any results.');
            }
        } else {
            error("Reverse Geocoding failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what browser are you using? your code looks good. the browser should be prompting you to allow access to your location. you need to grant access before the call will return.

Comment: that's my problem i tried other browsers like firefox ie & chrome still nothing i know it passes the first condition i tested it with an alert but it doesn't go further why don't know here's where i call my function maybe that will help

<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:getLocation();" ImageUrl="~/SharePostButton.png" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />

Comment: do you have an error function defined?

Comment: i did use an error function i tested if it fires it but it didn't so i just removed it

Comment: update: Unhandled exception at line 19, column 15349 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js

this pops up when i use ie with vs debugger

Comment: I didn't get an error with chrome. http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/tmp/location_test.html

Comment: can you update your jquery library to 1.6+. I remember having problems with IE9 using old jquery. What version of IE are you using?